# Ignore quotation marks when importing a CSV file into PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to import a tab-delimited file into my PostgreSQL database. One of the fields in my file is a "title" field, which occasionally contains actual quotation marks. For example, my tsv might look like:

```
id    title
5     Hello/Bleah" Foo
```

(Yeah, there's just that one quotation mark in the title.)

When I try importing the file into my database:

```
copy articles from 'articles.tsv' with delimiter E'\t' csv header;
```

I get this error, referencing that line:

```
ERROR:  unterminated CSV quoted field
```

How do I fix this? Quotation marks are never used to surround entire fields in the file. I tried `copy articles from 'articles.tsv' with delimiter E'\t' escape E'\\' csv header;` but I get the same error on the same line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tab separated is the default format for copy statements.  Treating them as CSV is just silly. (do you take this path just to skip the header ?)

```
copy articles from 'articles.tsv';
```

does exactly what you want.

Comment: Sounds simple enough, but what if the CSV data contains backslashes as valid field content? (yes, I've encountered this) The default format for COPY treats a backslash as an escape char, so then you HAVE to use COPY with CSV format...

Comment: I had not thought about that one. Yes: it makes sense.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming the file never actually tries to quote its fields:

The option you want is "with quote", see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-copy.html

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to turn off quote processing altogether, one kludge would be to specify a character that does not appear in your file at all.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I randomly tried `quote E'\b'`, which ended up working.

Comment: @grautur What does E'\b' mean? Backspace? what about the 'E'? "escape string constant" - got it.

Comment: @IanWarburton Yes, it seems it's a backspace: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%5Cb

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same error and a few more. Finally gathering knowledge from few SO questions I came up with the following setup for making COPY TO/FROM successful even for quite sophisticated JSON columns:

```
COPY "your_schema_name.yor_table_name" (your, column_names, here) 
FROM STDIN WITH CSV DELIMITER E'\t' QUOTE '\b' ESCAPE '\';
--here rows data
\.
```

the most important parts:

- `QUOTE '\b'` - quote with backspace (thanks a lot @grautur!)
- `DELIMITER E'\t'` - delimiter with tabs
- `ESCAPE '\'` - and escape with a backslash

Answer (score 0):

To copy from CSV file to PostgreSQL table with headers in CSV file using query:

- First Add all the files in C:/temp folder
- Then write the below scripts which accepts both **NULL** values as well as **EMPTY** strings

  ```
   copy PUBLIC."TABLE_NAME" FROM 
  'C:\tmp\TABLE_NAME.CSV' 
  (format csv, null "NULL", DELIMITER ',', HEADER);
  ```