# Is it possible to turn off quote processing in the Postgres COPY command with CSV format?

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I have CSV files, tab-separated, fields *not* wrapped in quotes, where field data can contain characters like single quotes, double quotes, pipes and backslashes.

Sample data can look like this:

```
1       2       "ba$aR\eR\       18
```

I want to import this data into Postgres using the COPY statement.

When I try to import this using

```
COPY <tablename> FROM  <filename> NULL AS '';
```

I get an error `psql:-:1: ERROR:  missing data for column` because Postgres is treating the backslash + tab as an "escaped tab" instead of a backslash followed by the field separator.

So I switched to using the "CSV format" of the COPY operator, like so:

```
COPY <tablename> FROM <filename> WITH CSV DELIMITER E'\t' NULL AS '';
```

Now there's a new error `psql:-:1: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(254)`

Apparently because it's interpreting the double-quote at the start of field 3 as the field wrapping character.

**How can I specify that my data is *NOT* quoted at all?**

Comment: why not post your workaround as answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore quotation marks when importing a CSV file into PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376322/ignore-quotation-marks-when-importing-a-csv-file-into-postgresql)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Workaround (thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376322/ignore-quotation-marks-when-importing-a-csv-file-into-postgresql#comment8905097_7376343)!)

```
COPY <tablename> FROM <filename> WITH CSV DELIMITER E'\t' QUOTE E'\b' NULL AS '';
```

So basically specifying a quote character that should never be in the text, but that's pretty ugly.

I'd much prefer it if there was in fact a way to turn off quote processing altogether.

Comment: @Kyle Barron's addition is crucial for some badly-encoded text. I have a very large (~50GB) CSV which I needed to copy and about 3GB before the end, '\b' appeared. The source for this file did a bad job in sanitizing values, but it doesn't mean I want my `COPY` to fail. `tr` to the rescue.

Answer (score 7):

(Added as a new answer since I don't have the reputation yet to comment.)

For the record, since I've been struggling with the same issue, you can use `tr` to remove `\b`, instead of just *hoping* it's not in your text anywhere.

```
tr -d '\010' < filename.csv > newfile.csv
```

(Using that `\010` is the [octal representation](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `\b`).

Since `COPY` supports reading from `STDIN`, you can ease the I/O impact by piping `tr`'s output:

```
cat filename.csv | tr -d '\010' | COPY <tablename> FROM STDIN WITH CSV DELIMITER E'\t' QUOTE E'\b' NULL AS '';
```

Answer (score 2):

The mode you want to use for data formatted as you describe is the default text mode. It will pass most characters unhindered into the database. It does not have quote processing, and it's using tabs as delimiters. Using CSV mode will just cause you trouble because you're introducing quoting that you have to work around.

Text mode will pass dollar characters, single and double quotes, pipes, and even back**spaces** (even though that was not mentioned in the question) right in. The one thing in the example that's not passed through is backslashes. But that's as simple as escaping them, for example by this `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' < source.txt > processed.txt
```

Then the processed file should be importable without any additional options:

```
\copy sometable from processed.txt
```