# Import CSV into SQL, one column has string " " with , as separate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a csv file with 7 columns. 6th column has value like "A,B,C" and 7th column has numbers, rest of the columns has int and text. While importing, 6th column is taking value A and 7th column with value B, but it should be like 6th column with ABC and 7th with int.

Comment: Should be a setting for Text Qualifier, you need to set that to use quotes.

Comment: What method are you using for importing?

Comment: If you are using the Import option, there should be a Quote Options tab. But as @tim said, what method are you using?

Comment: Also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041089/postgres-import-data-with-double-quote) should help you.